# Pip prompts for username + password despite extra index url credentials

Tags: python, pip, artifactory

When trying to access a private jFrog I am running into a credentials issue. Despite setting up a global extra index url, pip still asks me for my password.

`pip config debug` outputs:

```
env_var:
env:
global:
  /Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf, exists: True
site:
  /Users/***/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/pip.conf, exists: False
user:
  /Users/***/.pip/pip.conf, exists: True
    global.extra-index-url: https://***:***@***.jfrog.io/***/***/pypi/pypi-local/simple
  /Users/***/Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf, exists: False
```

Even when I pass the url directly as an extra index url: `pip install privatePackage --extra-index-url https://***:***@***.jfrog.io/***/***/pypi/pypi-local/simple`
I get the same result where it asks me for my login/password.

I have seen similar questions, but the answer is don't use any special characters in your password. My username and password are just alphanumeric characters.

I know that pip is able to access the private jFrog with the credentials since it is able to find the package before prompting me for my credentials again.
`Collecting privatePackage`